# Not able to create or access datasets in Jena Fuseki docker container

Tags: apache, jena, ontology, fuseki

I am using https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/master/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-docker to build a docker image for Apache Jena Fuseki.

I followed the exact same steps mentioned but I am not able to see an in-memory dataset when I use

```
ubuntu3@ubuntu3-VirtualBox:~$ sudo docker run -i --rm -p "3030:3030" --name MyServer -t fusekioriginal --debug --metrics --ping --mem /ds
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 3.17.0
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          :: Database: in-memory
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          :: Path = /ds
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Operation = query   Endpoints = [ "", "query", "sparql" ]
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Operation = update  Endpoints = [ "", "update" ]
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Operation = gsp-rw  Endpoints = [ "", "data" ]
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Operation = gsp-r   Endpoints = [ "get" ]
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Operation = upload  Endpoints = [ "upload" ]
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          :: System
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 1.9 GiB
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   Java:   14-ea
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Linux 5.8.0-43-generic amd64
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   PID:    1
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   java.vendor          = Oracle Corporation
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   java.home            = /opt/java-minimal
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   java.runtime.version = 14-ea+33
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   java.runtime.name    = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   user.language        = en
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   user.timezone        = GMT
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   user.country         = US
[2021-02-22 16:48:52] INFO  Server          ::   user.dir             = /fuseki
[2021-02-22 16:48:53] INFO  Server          :: Start Fuseki (port=3030)
```

on "http://localhost:3030/", I cannot see dataset ds created.

NOTE: I am completely new to dockerization and Apache Jena Fuseki server.

[Localhost:3030 Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7jyI.jpg)

[Localhost:3030/ds Snaphot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7HPl.jpg)

Comment: How are you trying to access it? Try http://localhost:3030/ds

If you try http://localhost:3030/, you should get a 404 - the server is there but there is no web resource at that address.

Comment: Hi AndyS, thanks for quick reply. I am able to see web interface on localhost:3030. When I try to access localhost:3030/ds, it gives me pop up to download a rdf file. Please find the snapshots attached in original post

Comment: Those screens shots are correct. http://localhost:3030/ds/ is a data service and in you config, it is a GSP (SPARQL Graph Store Protocol) because there is no query string. The HTTP GET request is asking for the database and you get back a TriG file (RDF data). If you want a HTML page to query the database, go to the query button (below what is shown in screenshot one) or do to the "dataset" tab.

Comment: When I click on query it gives me 'Please select a dataset' message. And when I try to create one using 'Manage Datasets', the WebUI does not respond with any UI to add new dataset.

Comment: I've realised The screenshots you show are from "Fuseki full" (the packing with UI), the output seems to be from "Fuskei main" (no UI - and does not include the server side code for the UI functions). How did you build the docker image?  If you used the instructions at: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-docker ==> "There is no UI". (There is a pull request outstanding for the full server, needs to be integrated sometime.)

Comment: Hi AndyS, what you pointed out is correct. Indeed its mentioned "There is no UI" in [link](jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-docker). I am not sure why I was able to see the UI partially. My wild guess would be because I was trying some non-official docker images with UI parallelly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dockerfile available at https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-docker, generates a docker image "with NO UI". Hence, webapp will not be available.